# How to replay a game once GAME OVER comes without closing the program and running it again in PYGAME?

Tags: python, pygame

I have made a Ping-Pong game in python: Pygame. Its running perfectly, and i decided to fix some of its loopholes. At the end when the GAME OVER screen displays, i have to close my game and then go back to my main source code and run it again. So i have decided to add a message "Press a key to play", and i have also added a function to check key press. The message is displayed but once a key is pressed, it isn't able to detect that.
This is the `checkForKeyPress():` code:

```
def checkForKeyPress():
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if not any(keys): return False
    if keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
        exit()
    return True
```

And this is my source code:

```
import pygame
import sys
import random
from math import *

pygame.init()

width = 600
height = 400
display = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Ping Pong!")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

BASICFONT = pygame.font.SysFont('freesansbold.ttf', 22)

print("Use the arrow up key to slide or arrow down key to slide down. Thanks for playing! Nishita Thakur.")

background = (27, 38, 49)
white = (236, 240, 241)
red = (203, 67, 53)
blue = (52, 152, 219)
yellow = (244, 208, 63)
DARKGRAY = (90, 90, 90)

top = white
bottom = white
left = white
right = white

margin = 4

scoreLeft = 0
scoreRight = 0
maxScore = 1

font = pygame.font.SysFont("Small Fonts", 30)
largeFont = pygame.font.SysFont("Small Fonts", 60)

# Draw the Boundary of Board
def boundary():
    global top, bottom, left, right
    pygame.draw.rect(display, left, (0, 0, margin, height))
    pygame.draw.rect(display, top, (0, 0, width, margin))
    pygame.draw.rect(display, right, (width-margin, 0, margin, height))
    pygame.draw.rect(display, bottom, (0, height - margin, width, margin))

    l = 25
    
    pygame.draw.rect(display, white, (width/2-margin/2, 10, margin, l))
    pygame.draw.rect(display, white, (width/2-margin/2, 60, margin, l))
    pygame.draw.rect(display, white, (width/2-margin/2, 110, margin, l))
    pygame.draw.rect(display, white, (width/2-margin/2, 160, margin, l))
    pygame.draw.rect(display, white, (width/2-margin/2, 210, margin, l))
    pygame.draw.rect(display, white, (width/2-margin/2, 260, margin, l))
    pygame.draw.rect(display, white, (width/2-margin/2, 310, margin, l))
    pygame.draw.rect(display, white, (width/2-margin/2, 360, margin, l))
    
# Paddle Class 
class Paddle:
    def __init__(self, position):
        self.w = 10
        self.h = self.w*8
        self.paddleSpeed = 6
            
        if position == -1:
            self.x = 1.5*margin
        else:
            self.x = width - 1.5*margin - self.w
            
        self.y = height/2 - self.h/2

    # Show the Paddle
    def show(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(display, white, (self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h))

    # Move the Paddle
    def move(self, ydir):
        self.y += self.paddleSpeed*ydir
        if self.y < 0:
            self.y -= self.paddleSpeed*ydir
        elif self.y + self.h> height:
            self.y -= self.paddleSpeed*ydir


leftPaddle = Paddle(-1)
rightPaddle = Paddle(1)

# Ball Class

    
def drawPressKeyMsg():
    pressKeySurf = BASICFONT.render('Press a key to play.', True, DARKGRAY)
    pressKeyRect = pressKeySurf.get_rect()
    pressKeyRect.topleft = (width - 142, height - 25)
    display.blit(pressKeySurf, pressKeyRect)
    checkForKeyPress()
    
def checkForKeyPress():
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if not any(keys): return False
    if keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
        exit()
    return True

class Ball:
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.r = 20
        self.x = width/2 - self.r/2
        self.y = height/2 -self.r/2
        self.color = color
        self.angle = random.randint(-75, 75)
        if random.randint(0, 1):
            self.angle += 180
        
        self.speed = 8

    # Show the Ball
    def show(self):
        pygame.draw.ellipse(display, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.r, self.r))

    # Move the Ball
    def move(self):
        global scoreLeft, scoreRight
        self.x += self.speed*cos(radians(self.angle))
        self.y += self.speed*sin(radians(self.angle))
        if self.x + self.r > width - margin:
            scoreLeft += 1
            self.angle = 180 - self.angle
        if self.x < margin:
            scoreRight += 1
            self.angle = 180 - self.angle
        if self.y < margin:
            self.angle = - self.angle
        if self.y + self.r  >=height - margin:
            self.angle = - self.angle

    # Check and Reflect the Ball when it hits the padddle
    def checkForPaddle(self):
        if self.x < width/2:
            if leftPaddle.x < self.x < leftPaddle.x + leftPaddle.w:
                if leftPaddle.y < self.y < leftPaddle.y + 10 or leftPaddle.y < self.y + self.r< leftPaddle.y + 10:
                    self.angle = -45
                if leftPaddle.y + 10 < self.y < leftPaddle.y + 20 or leftPaddle.y + 10 < self.y + self.r< leftPaddle.y + 20:
                    self.angle = -30
                if leftPaddle.y + 20 < self.y < leftPaddle.y + 30 or leftPaddle.y + 20 < self.y + self.r< leftPaddle.y + 30:
                    self.angle = -15
                if leftPaddle.y + 30 < self.y < leftPaddle.y + 40 or leftPaddle.y + 30 < self.y + self.r< leftPaddle.y + 40:
                    self.angle = -10
                if leftPaddle.y + 40 < self.y < leftPaddle.y + 50 or leftPaddle.y + 40 < self.y + self.r< leftPaddle.y + 50:
                    self.angle = 10
                if leftPaddle.y + 50 < self.y < leftPaddle.y + 60 or leftPaddle.y + 50 < self.y + self.r< leftPaddle.y + 60:
                    self.angle = 15
                if leftPaddle.y + 60 < self.y < leftPaddle.y + 70 or leftPaddle.y + 60 < self.y + self.r< leftPaddle.y + 70:
                    self.angle = 30
                if leftPaddle.y + 70 < self.y < leftPaddle.y + 80 or leftPaddle.y + 70 < self.y + self.r< leftPaddle.y + 80:
                    self.angle = 45
        else:
            if rightPaddle.x + rightPaddle.w > self.x  + self.r > rightPaddle.x:
                if rightPaddle.y < self.y < leftPaddle.y + 10 or leftPaddle.y < self.y + self.r< leftPaddle.y + 10:
                    self.angle = -135
                if rightPaddle.y + 10 < self.y < rightPaddle.y + 20 or rightPaddle.y + 10 < self.y + self.r< rightPaddle.y + 20:
                    self.angle = -150
                if rightPaddle.y + 20 < self.y < rightPaddle.y + 30 or rightPaddle.y + 20 < self.y + self.r< rightPaddle.y + 30:
                    self.angle = -165
                if rightPaddle.y + 30 < self.y < rightPaddle.y + 40 or rightPaddle.y + 30 < self.y + self.r< rightPaddle.y + 40:
                    self.angle = 170
                if rightPaddle.y + 40 < self.y < rightPaddle.y + 50 or rightPaddle.y + 40 < self.y + self.r< rightPaddle.y + 50:
                    self.angle = 190
                if rightPaddle.y + 50 < self.y < rightPaddle.y + 60 or rightPaddle.y + 50 < self.y + self.r< rightPaddle.y + 60:
                    self.angle = 165
                if rightPaddle.y + 60 < self.y < rightPaddle.y + 70 or rightPaddle.y + 60 < self.y + self.r< rightPaddle.y + 70:
                    self.angle = 150
                if rightPaddle.y + 70 < self.y < rightPaddle.y + 80 or rightPaddle.y + 70 < self.y + self.r< rightPaddle.y + 80:
                     self.angle = 135

# Show the Score
def showScore():
    leftScoreText = font.render("Score : " + str(scoreLeft), True, red)
    rightScoreText = font.render("Score : " + str(scoreRight), True, blue)

    display.blit(leftScoreText, (3*margin, 3*margin))
    display.blit(rightScoreText, (width/2 + 3*margin, 3*margin))

# Game Over
def gameOver():
    if scoreLeft == maxScore or scoreRight == maxScore:
        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    close()
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                        close()
                    if event.key == pygame.K_r:
                        reset()
            if scoreLeft == maxScore:
                playerWins = largeFont.render("Left Player Wins!", True, red)
            elif scoreRight == maxScore:
                playerWins = largeFont.render("Right Player Wins!", True, blue)
            drawPressKeyMsg()
            checkForKeyPress()                        
           
           
           #isGameOver = False # determines whether game is lose
           #gameStatus = True # game is still running

           #score = 0 # score for the game.

            display.blit(playerWins, (width/2 - 185, height/2-35))
            pygame.display.update()

def reset():
    global scoreLeft, scoreRight
    scoreLeft = 0
    scoreRight = 0
    board()


def close():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()

def board():
    loop = True
    leftChange = 0
    rightChange = 0
    ball = Ball(yellow)
    
    while loop:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                close()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                    close()
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE or event.key == pygame.K_p:
                    Pause()
                if event.key == pygame.K_r:
                    reset()
                if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    leftChange = -1
                if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    leftChange = 1
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    rightChange = -1
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    rightChange = 1
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                leftChange = 0
                rightChange = 0

        leftPaddle.move(leftChange)
        rightPaddle.move(rightChange)
        ball.move()
        ball.checkForPaddle() 
        
        display.fill(background)
        showScore()

        ball.show()
        leftPaddle.show()
        rightPaddle.show()

        boundary()

        gameOver()
        
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)

board()
```

Thanks in advance! Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a function that initialize all the game states:

```py
def initGame():
    global scoreLeft, scoreRight
    global leftPaddle, rightPaddle
    global ball
    scoreLeft = 0
    scoreRight = 0
    leftPaddle = Paddle(-1)
    rightPaddle = Paddle(1)
    ball = Ball(yellow)
```

Note, `ball` has to be constructed in `initGame` rather than `board`.

Invoke `initGame`, before the `bard`:

```py
initGame()
board()
```

Call `initGame` again if the game needs to be reset:

```py
def checkForKeyPress():
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if not any(keys): return False
    if keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
        close()
    initGame()
    return True
```

```py
def reset():
    initGame()
```

Continue the  `while`-loop in `gameOver` as long one of the scores is equal to  `maxScore`:

```py
def gameOver():
    while scoreLeft == maxScore or scoreRight == maxScore:
        # [...]
```

---

Complete code:

```py
import pygame
import sys
import random
from math import *

pygame.init()

width = 600
height = 400
display = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Ping Pong!")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

BASICFONT = pygame.font.SysFont('freesansbold.ttf', 22)

print("Use the arrow up key to slide or arrow down key to slide down. Thanks for playing! Nishita Thakur.")

background = (27, 38, 49)
white = (236, 240, 241)
red = (203, 67, 53)
blue = (52, 152, 219)
yellow = (244, 208, 63)
DARKGRAY = (90, 90, 90)

top = white
bottom = white
left = white
right = white

margin = 4

scoreLeft = 0
scoreRight = 0
maxScore = 1

font = pygame.font.SysFont("Small Fonts", 30)
largeFont = pygame.font.SysFont("Small Fonts", 60)

# Draw the Boundary of Board
def boundary():
    global top, bottom, left, right
    pygame.draw.rect(display, left, (0, 0, margin, height))
    pygame.draw.rect(display, top, (0, 0, width, margin))
    pygame.draw.rect(display, right, (width-margin, 0, margin, height))
    pygame.draw.rect(display, bottom, (0, height - margin, width, margin))

    l = 25
    
    pygame.draw.rect(display, white, (width/2-margin/2, 10, margin, l))
    pygame.draw.rect(display, white, (width/2-margin/2, 60, margin, l))
    pygame.draw.rect(display, white, (width/2-margin/2, 110, margin, l))
    pygame.draw.rect(display, white, (width/2-margin/2, 160, margin, l))
    pygame.draw.rect(display, white, (width/2-margin/2, 210, margin, l))
    pygame.draw.rect(display, white, (width/2-margin/2, 260, margin, l))
    pygame.draw.rect(display, white, (width/2-margin/2, 310, margin, l))
    pygame.draw.rect(display, white, (width/2-margin/2, 360, margin, l))
    
# Paddle Class 
class Paddle:
    def __init__(self, position):
        self.w = 10
        self.h = self.w*8
        self.paddleSpeed = 6
            
        if position == -1:
            self.x = 1.5*margin
        else:
            self.x = width - 1.5*margin - self.w
            
        self.y = height/2 - self.h/2

    # Show the Paddle
    def show(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(display, white, (self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h))

    # Move the Paddle
    def move(self, ydir):
        self.y += self.paddleSpeed*ydir
        if self.y < 0:
            self.y -= self.paddleSpeed*ydir
        elif self.y + self.h> height:
            self.y -= self.paddleSpeed*ydir


# Ball Class

    
def drawPressKeyMsg():
    pressKeySurf = BASICFONT.render('Press a key to play.', True, DARKGRAY)
    pressKeyRect = pressKeySurf.get_rect()
    pressKeyRect.topleft = (width - 142, height - 25)
    display.blit(pressKeySurf, pressKeyRect)
    checkForKeyPress()
    
def checkForKeyPress():
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if not any(keys): return False
    if keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
        close()
    initGame()
    return True

class Ball:
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.r = 20
        self.x = width/2 - self.r/2
        self.y = height/2 -self.r/2
        self.color = color
        self.angle = random.randint(-75, 75)
        if random.randint(0, 1):
            self.angle += 180
        
        self.speed = 8

    # Show the Ball
    def show(self):
        pygame.draw.ellipse(display, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.r, self.r))

    # Move the Ball
    def move(self):
        global scoreLeft, scoreRight
        self.x += self.speed*cos(radians(self.angle))
        self.y += self.speed*sin(radians(self.angle))
        if self.x + self.r > width - margin:
            scoreLeft += 1
            self.angle = 180 - self.angle
        if self.x < margin:
            scoreRight += 1
            self.angle = 180 - self.angle
        if self.y < margin:
            self.angle = - self.angle
        if self.y + self.r  >=height - margin:
            self.angle = - self.angle

    # Check and Reflect the Ball when it hits the padddle
    def checkForPaddle(self):
        if self.x < width/2:
            if leftPaddle.x < self.x < leftPaddle.x + leftPaddle.w:
                if leftPaddle.y < self.y < leftPaddle.y + 10 or leftPaddle.y < self.y + self.r< leftPaddle.y + 10:
                    self.angle = -45
                if leftPaddle.y + 10 < self.y < leftPaddle.y + 20 or leftPaddle.y + 10 < self.y + self.r< leftPaddle.y + 20:
                    self.angle = -30
                if leftPaddle.y + 20 < self.y < leftPaddle.y + 30 or leftPaddle.y + 20 < self.y + self.r< leftPaddle.y + 30:
                    self.angle = -15
                if leftPaddle.y + 30 < self.y < leftPaddle.y + 40 or leftPaddle.y + 30 < self.y + self.r< leftPaddle.y + 40:
                    self.angle = -10
                if leftPaddle.y + 40 < self.y < leftPaddle.y + 50 or leftPaddle.y + 40 < self.y + self.r< leftPaddle.y + 50:
                    self.angle = 10
                if leftPaddle.y + 50 < self.y < leftPaddle.y + 60 or leftPaddle.y + 50 < self.y + self.r< leftPaddle.y + 60:
                    self.angle = 15
                if leftPaddle.y + 60 < self.y < leftPaddle.y + 70 or leftPaddle.y + 60 < self.y + self.r< leftPaddle.y + 70:
                    self.angle = 30
                if leftPaddle.y + 70 < self.y < leftPaddle.y + 80 or leftPaddle.y + 70 < self.y + self.r< leftPaddle.y + 80:
                    self.angle = 45
        else:
            if rightPaddle.x + rightPaddle.w > self.x  + self.r > rightPaddle.x:
                if rightPaddle.y < self.y < leftPaddle.y + 10 or leftPaddle.y < self.y + self.r< leftPaddle.y + 10:
                    self.angle = -135
                if rightPaddle.y + 10 < self.y < rightPaddle.y + 20 or rightPaddle.y + 10 < self.y + self.r< rightPaddle.y + 20:
                    self.angle = -150
                if rightPaddle.y + 20 < self.y < rightPaddle.y + 30 or rightPaddle.y + 20 < self.y + self.r< rightPaddle.y + 30:
                    self.angle = -165
                if rightPaddle.y + 30 < self.y < rightPaddle.y + 40 or rightPaddle.y + 30 < self.y + self.r< rightPaddle.y + 40:
                    self.angle = 170
                if rightPaddle.y + 40 < self.y < rightPaddle.y + 50 or rightPaddle.y + 40 < self.y + self.r< rightPaddle.y + 50:
                    self.angle = 190
                if rightPaddle.y + 50 < self.y < rightPaddle.y + 60 or rightPaddle.y + 50 < self.y + self.r< rightPaddle.y + 60:
                    self.angle = 165
                if rightPaddle.y + 60 < self.y < rightPaddle.y + 70 or rightPaddle.y + 60 < self.y + self.r< rightPaddle.y + 70:
                    self.angle = 150
                if rightPaddle.y + 70 < self.y < rightPaddle.y + 80 or rightPaddle.y + 70 < self.y + self.r< rightPaddle.y + 80:
                     self.angle = 135

# Show the Score
def showScore():
    leftScoreText = font.render("Score : " + str(scoreLeft), True, red)
    rightScoreText = font.render("Score : " + str(scoreRight), True, blue)

    display.blit(leftScoreText, (3*margin, 3*margin))
    display.blit(rightScoreText, (width/2 + 3*margin, 3*margin))

# Game Over
def gameOver():
    while scoreLeft == maxScore or scoreRight == maxScore:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                close()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                    close()
                if event.key == pygame.K_r:
                    reset()
        if scoreLeft == maxScore:
            playerWins = largeFont.render("Left Player Wins!", True, red)
        elif scoreRight == maxScore:
            playerWins = largeFont.render("Right Player Wins!", True, blue)
        drawPressKeyMsg()
        checkForKeyPress()                        
        
        
        #isGameOver = False # determines whether game is lose
        #gameStatus = True # game is still running

        #score = 0 # score for the game.

        display.blit(playerWins, (width/2 - 185, height/2-35))
        pygame.display.update()

def reset():
    initGame()

def initGame():
    global scoreLeft, scoreRight
    global leftPaddle, rightPaddle
    global ball
    scoreLeft = 0
    scoreRight = 0
    leftPaddle = Paddle(-1)
    rightPaddle = Paddle(1)
    ball = Ball(yellow)


def close():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()

def board():
    loop = True
    leftChange = 0
    rightChange = 0
   
    while loop:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                close()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                    close()
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE or event.key == pygame.K_p:
                    Pause()
                if event.key == pygame.K_r:
                    reset()
                if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    leftChange = -1
                if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    leftChange = 1
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    rightChange = -1
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    rightChange = 1
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                leftChange = 0
                rightChange = 0

        leftPaddle.move(leftChange)
        rightPaddle.move(rightChange)
        ball.move()
        ball.checkForPaddle() 
        
        display.fill(background)
        showScore()

        ball.show()
        leftPaddle.show()
        rightPaddle.show()

        boundary()

        gameOver()
        
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)

initGame()
board()
```

Comment: my desired output was that i wanted that once the GAME OVER screen comes, and i press a key, the game starts again.

Comment: @NishitaThakur Now I got it you want the game to be exit when ESC is pressed, but you want it to be continued when any other key is pressed. Now I see. I thought you want the game to be continued when ESC i pressed. I apologize, I didn't get that. I've changed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pygame
import sys
import random
from math import *

pygame.init()

width = 600
height = 400
display = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Ping Pong!")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

BASICFONT = pygame.font.SysFont('freesansbold.ttf', 22)

print("Use the arrow up key to slide or arrow down key to slide down. Thanks for playing! Nishita Thakur.")

background = (27, 38, 49)
white = (236, 240, 241)
red = (203, 67, 53)
blue = (52, 152, 219)
yellow = (244, 208, 63)
DARKGRAY = (90, 90, 90)

top = white
bottom = white
left = white
right = white

margin = 4

scoreLeft = 0
scoreRight = 0
maxScore = 20

font = pygame.font.SysFont("Small Fonts", 30)
largeFont = pygame.font.SysFont("Small Fonts", 60)

# Draw the Boundary of Board
def boundary():
    global top, bottom, left, right
    pygame.draw.rect(display, left, (0, 0, margin, height))
    pygame.draw.rect(display, top, (0, 0, width, margin))
    pygame.draw.rect(display, right, (width-margin, 0, margin, height))
    pygame.draw.rect(display, bottom, (0, height - margin, width, margin))

    l = 25
    
    pygame.draw.rect(display, white, (width/2-margin/2, 10, margin, l))
    pygame.draw.rect(display, white, (width/2-margin/2, 60, margin, l))
    pygame.draw.rect(display, white, (width/2-margin/2, 110, margin, l))
    pygame.draw.rect(display, white, (width/2-margin/2, 160, margin, l))
    pygame.draw.rect(display, white, (width/2-margin/2, 210, margin, l))
    pygame.draw.rect(display, white, (width/2-margin/2, 260, margin, l))
    pygame.draw.rect(display, white, (width/2-margin/2, 310, margin, l))
    pygame.draw.rect(display, white, (width/2-margin/2, 360, margin, l))
    
# Paddle Class 
class Paddle:
    def __init__(self, position):
        self.w = 10
        self.h = self.w*8
        self.paddleSpeed = 6
            
        if position == -1:
            self.x = 1.5*margin
        else:
            self.x = width - 1.5*margin - self.w
            
        self.y = height/2 - self.h/2

    # Show the Paddle
    def show(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(display, white, (self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h))

    # Move the Paddle
    def move(self, ydir):
        self.y += self.paddleSpeed*ydir
        if self.y < 0:
            self.y -= self.paddleSpeed*ydir
        elif self.y + self.h> height:
            self.y -= self.paddleSpeed*ydir


# Ball Class

    
def drawPressKeyMsg():
    pressKeySurf = BASICFONT.render('Press a key to play.', True, DARKGRAY)
    pressKeyRect = pressKeySurf.get_rect()
    pressKeyRect.topleft = (width - 142, height - 25)
    display.blit(pressKeySurf, pressKeyRect)
    checkForKeyPress()
    
def checkForKeyPress():
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if not any(keys): return False
    if keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
        exit()
    return initGame()

class Ball:
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.r = 20
        self.x = width/2 - self.r/2
        self.y = height/2 -self.r/2
        self.color = color
        self.angle = random.randint(-75, 75)
        if random.randint(0, 1):
            self.angle += 180
        
        self.speed = 8

    # Show the Ball
    def show(self):
                pygame.draw.ellipse(display, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.r, self.r))

    # Move the Ball
    def move(self):
        global scoreLeft, scoreRight
        self.x += self.speed*cos(radians(self.angle))
        self.y += self.speed*sin(radians(self.angle))
        if self.x + self.r > width - margin:
            scoreLeft += 1
            self.angle = 180 - self.angle
        if self.x < margin:
            scoreRight += 1
            self.angle = 180 - self.angle
        if self.y < margin:
            self.angle = - self.angle
        if self.y + self.r  >=height - margin:
            self.angle = - self.angle

    # Check and Reflect the Ball when it hits the padddle
    def checkForPaddle(self):
        if self.x < width/2:
            if leftPaddle.x < self.x < leftPaddle.x + leftPaddle.w:
                if leftPaddle.y < self.y < leftPaddle.y + 10 or leftPaddle.y < self.y + self.r< leftPaddle.y + 10:
                    self.angle = -45
                if leftPaddle.y + 10 < self.y < leftPaddle.y + 20 or leftPaddle.y + 10 < self.y + self.r< leftPaddle.y + 20:
                    self.angle = -30
                if leftPaddle.y + 20 < self.y < leftPaddle.y + 30 or leftPaddle.y + 20 < self.y + self.r< leftPaddle.y + 30:
                    self.angle = -15
                if leftPaddle.y + 30 < self.y < leftPaddle.y + 40 or leftPaddle.y + 30 < self.y + self.r< leftPaddle.y + 40:
                    self.angle = -10
                if leftPaddle.y + 40 < self.y < leftPaddle.y + 50 or leftPaddle.y + 40 < self.y + self.r< leftPaddle.y + 50:
                    self.angle = 10
                if leftPaddle.y + 50 < self.y < leftPaddle.y + 60 or leftPaddle.y + 50 < self.y + self.r< leftPaddle.y + 60:
                    self.angle = 15
                if leftPaddle.y + 60 < self.y < leftPaddle.y + 70 or leftPaddle.y + 60 < self.y + self.r< leftPaddle.y + 70:
                    self.angle = 30
                if leftPaddle.y + 70 < self.y < leftPaddle.y + 80 or leftPaddle.y + 70 < self.y + self.r< leftPaddle.y + 80:
                    self.angle = 45
        else:
            if rightPaddle.x + rightPaddle.w > self.x  + self.r > rightPaddle.x:
                if rightPaddle.y < self.y < leftPaddle.y + 10 or leftPaddle.y < self.y + self.r< leftPaddle.y + 10:
                    self.angle = -135
                if rightPaddle.y + 10 < self.y < rightPaddle.y + 20 or rightPaddle.y + 10 < self.y + self.r< rightPaddle.y + 20:
                    self.angle = -150
                if rightPaddle.y + 20 < self.y < rightPaddle.y + 30 or rightPaddle.y + 20 < self.y + self.r< rightPaddle.y + 30:
                    self.angle = -165
                if rightPaddle.y + 30 < self.y < rightPaddle.y + 40 or rightPaddle.y + 30 < self.y + self.r< rightPaddle.y + 40:
                    self.angle = 170
                if rightPaddle.y + 40 < self.y < rightPaddle.y + 50 or rightPaddle.y + 40 < self.y + self.r< rightPaddle.y + 50:
                    self.angle = 190
                if rightPaddle.y + 50 < self.y < rightPaddle.y + 60 or rightPaddle.y + 50 < self.y + self.r< rightPaddle.y + 60:
                    self.angle = 165
                if rightPaddle.y + 60 < self.y < rightPaddle.y + 70 or rightPaddle.y + 60 < self.y + self.r< rightPaddle.y + 70:
                    self.angle = 150
                if rightPaddle.y + 70 < self.y < rightPaddle.y + 80 or rightPaddle.y + 70 < self.y + self.r< rightPaddle.y + 80:
                     self.angle = 135

# Show the Score
def showScore():
    leftScoreText = font.render("Score : " + str(scoreLeft), True, red)
    rightScoreText = font.render("Score : " + str(scoreRight), True, blue)

    display.blit(leftScoreText, (3*margin, 3*margin))
    display.blit(rightScoreText, (width/2 + 3*margin, 3*margin))

# Game Over
def gameOver():
    while scoreLeft == maxScore or scoreRight == maxScore:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                close()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                    close()
                if event.key == pygame.K_r:
                    reset()
        if scoreLeft == maxScore:
            playerWins = largeFont.render("Left Player Wins!", True, red)
            drawPressKeyMsg()
            checkForKeyPress()  
        elif scoreRight == maxScore:
            playerWins = largeFont.render("Right Player Wins!", True, blue)
            drawPressKeyMsg()
            checkForKeyPress()                    
        
        
        #isGameOver = False # determines whether game is lose
        #gameStatus = True # game is still running

        #score = 0 # score for the game.

        display.blit(playerWins, (width/2 - 185, height/2-35))
        pygame.display.update()

def reset():
    initGame()

def initGame():
    global scoreLeft, scoreRight
    global leftPaddle, rightPaddle
    global ball
    scoreLeft = 0
    scoreRight = 0
    leftPaddle = Paddle(-1)
    rightPaddle = Paddle(1)
    ball = Ball(yellow)


def close():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()

def board():
    loop = True
    leftChange = 0
    rightChange = 0
   
    while loop:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                close()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                    close()
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE or event.key == pygame.K_p:
                    Pause()
                if event.key == pygame.K_r:
                    reset()
                if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    leftChange = -1
                if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    leftChange = 1
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    rightChange = -1
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    rightChange = 1
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                leftChange = 0
                rightChange = 0

        leftPaddle.move(leftChange)
        rightPaddle.move(rightChange)
        ball.move()
        ball.checkForPaddle() 
        
        display.fill(background)
        showScore()

        ball.show()
        leftPaddle.show()
        rightPaddle.show()

        boundary()

        gameOver()
        
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)

initGame()
board()
```

This is the code which helped me get my desired output.
These are some modifications i did to `checkForKeyPress():` function:

```
def checkForKeyPress():
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if not any(keys): return False
    if keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
        exit()
    return initGame()
```